# Regular Expression Remove '-' between characters

Tags: regex, calibre

I'm trying to use Regular expressions, to remove '-' character that is inside a word.
I know how to find them, just by`[A-z]-[A-z]`, but how do i remove only the '-'?
In more detail, I converted a PDF to EPUB using Calibre, and it has done a much better work than i expected, and the problem now is that words that broke between pages have this annoying '-'.

Thanks

Comment: FYI `[A-z]` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<=\p{L})-(?=\p{L})/` (or `/(?<=[[:alpha:]])-(?=[[:alpha:]])/`) will match a hyphen between two Unicode uppercase or lowercase letters. `(?<=\p{L})` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?<\p{L})` is a *positive lookahead*. For English text you could also write `/(?<=[a-z])-(?=[1-z])/`, provided one does not write `"She was blas-é about it"`.

In Ruby,

```
"She- wa-s blas-é about it".gsub(/(?<=\p{L})-(?=\p{L})/, '')
  #=> "She- was blasé about it"

"He double-downed--shall we say--on his efforts".
  gsub(/(?<=\p{L})-(?=\p{L})/, '')
  #=> "He doubledowned--shall we say--on his efforts"
```

Answer (score -1):

A regex itself won't handle replacements, only identifying matches. It's the language's implementation of regex that has capabilities to do a replace.

In JavaScript you can use String.replace with regex capture groups to remove the - from inside a word like this:

`'This is anno-ying. This is also anno-ying'.replace(/(\w)-(\w)/g, function (m, p1, p2) { return p1+p2 })`

returns

`'This is annoying. This is also annoying'`

This will only replace dashes if they appear adjacent to two word characters (as defined by regex).

Comment: It will replace the first hyphen only and in any context whild OP expects to only match them in between letters.

Comment: Edited to more accurately answer the question. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately capturing group at the end of the pattern will prevent consecutive matches. Cary's solution is correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tested this and it does work with consecutive hyphens: `'This is anno-ying. This is also anno-ying'.replace(/(\w)-(\w)/g, function (m, p1, p2) { return p1+p2 })` returns `'This is annoying. This is also annoying'` I believe this is because JavaScript executes the replacement function once for each match.

Comment: Those are not consecutive matches. Try with `a-b-c` as input.